# error in calling web service through Internet Explorer

Tags: xml, web-services

When i type the url of my web service i'm trying to access (via IE), instead of displaying its list of operations, an error is displayed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?> 
- <Error number="901">
- <Description>
- <![CDATA[ 
SERVEUR : GHMWBTVW01
PCFWKCNET (module PCFWKWINCLIENT) : version 2.10.12
INSTANCE APPELEE : CNET_VA_DPLAN_API
UTILISATEUR : 
POSTE APPELANT : <browser><ip>10.2.0.220</ip><ie>8.0</ie><os>WinNT</os></browser>
DETAIL : Lecture de la requete Xml impossible 
PILE D'APPEL .NET :    à System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   à System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowWithoutLineInfo(String res)
   à System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()...
```

what could be the cause?

Comment: Define what "Navigator" actually is. Rings of Netscape Navigator 4.7 go through my ears, but that's certainly not the case; it's probably some element of your development environment. Add tags for the software you use!

Comment: @MarcusMüller Navigator=Internet Explorer. I am trying to access the webservice by typing the url in IE

Comment: Ok, that makes sense, considering the `<browser><ie>8.0</ie></browser>`. Isn't IE8 ancient by now?

Comment: @MarcusMüller does the version of IE matter?